# SSH Honeypot: pros/cons?

Tags: linux, ssh, security, honeypot

My aim is to improve the security of my Raspberry Pi. The server needs to be open to the world through SSH, and I have already taken the usual measures to beef up the SSH security: primarily, fail2ban and non-standard port.

I am debating the use of a honeypot on top of this. [Kippo](http://kojoney.sourceforge.net/) comes to mind. However, since it adds more moving parts to my system, my fear is that could open up to new vulnerabilities.

On the other hand, I think it could be advantageous to have a honeypot on a somewhat standard port (eg. 222) to prevent attackers from moving to the real port. Or, is this of little use? Will most attackers do a complete port scan anyway?

I am no expert, what are you recommendations?

Comment: Actually, the "usual measure" is public key auth and nothing but. There’s no real need for anything else.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/ *might* be a more relevant place for this question.

Comment: A honeypot will only reduce your security, not increase it. Simply put, it is additional attack surface.